# React access state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm building a reports page. I create a ReportForm component with the search options for the reports and I'm including this ReportForm in my Reports component.

I'm trying to get the state from ReportForm.js in Reports.js

ReportForm.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import DateRangePicker from 'react-bootstrap-daterangepicker';
import * as action from '../store/actions/index';

class ReportForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            reports: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        await this.props.onLoadReport();
        this.setState({ reports: this.props.reports });
    }

    handleSelect = (start, end, label) => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: start._d,
            endDate: end._d
        });
    }

    getDateRanges = () => {
        const today = new Date();
        const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
        const last = first + 6;
        
        return {
            'Today': [today, today],
            'This Week': [
                new Date(today.setDate(first)),
                new Date(today.setDate(last))
            ],
            'This Month': [
                new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1),
                new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0)
            ],
            'This Year': [
                new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1),
                new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31)
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        const sDate = this.state.startDate.toLocaleDateString();
        const eDate = this.state.endDate.toLocaleDateString();
        const reports = this.state.reports;
        const initDates = {
            startDate: sDate,
            endDate: eDate,
            showDropdowns: true,
            ranges: this.getDateRanges()
        };
        return (
            <div className="row" style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}>
                <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <table className="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th className="text-center">Report</th>
                                <th className="text-center col-sm-4">Period</th>
                                <th className="text-center col-sm-3">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <select className="form-control" id="report">
                                        {reports.map((values, index) => {
                                            return (
                                                <option value={Object.keys(values)[0]}>{Object.values(values)[0]}</option>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <DateRangePicker
                                        initialSettings={initDates}
                                        onCallback={this.handleSelect}
                                    >
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                                    </DateRangePicker>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center"><button className="btn btn-success">Run Report</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        reports: state.report.reports
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLoadReport: () => dispatch(action.getReports())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReportForm);
```

Here is my Reports.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReportForm from './ReportForm';

class Reports extends Component {

    render() {
        // How can I get state.startDate, state.endDate from ReportForm.js ?
       
        return (
            <div>
                <ReportForm />

                <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Reports;
```

Comment: Simply put - you cannot, u need to lift the state up or use context, or use redux.
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: you can use recoil as well

Comment: What is recoil?

Comment: it's reacts state management library

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Communication between React components you make on one away. Component who send data , send this data like state. Component who receive data, he receive data like props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any other details about what you're doing, the typical way to share state is for it to be "owned" by the parent and passed into the child.  So you might move the state you've defined here to `Reports`, then the data that is required by `ReportForm` can be passed in via that component's `props` (not state).  If the child needs to perform operations determined by the parent, or change the data, it should also receive callback functions (in props) from the parent for doing that.

(Side note: since you say you are just learning React, it might be worth mentioning that the React devs encourage the use of "hooks" rather than classes for new React development.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to change my Components to be hooks, but it stop working with my Redux

Comment: Thank you. After a day reading about Hooks, it is definitely the best option. I don't need Redux at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would pass a `onSubmit` callback to `ReportForm`:

```html
<ReportForm onSubmit={myCallback} />
```

Then I would call this callback with the state from the `ReportForm` component when the form is submitted.

Comment: Could you please explain how the onSubmit works?

Comment: The `onSubmit` function will be accessible from your inner component props: `const { onSubmit } = props;`

Then you can use it.

Comment: The side effect is you can not use this to update your outter component state unless it will go in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReportForm from './ReportForm';

class Reports extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
}

updateState(data){
     this.setState(data)
}


render() {
    // How can I get state.startDate, state.endDate from ReportForm.js ?
   
    return (
        <div>
            <ReportForm state={this.state} updateState={this.updateState}/>

            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <h2>Content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
};

export default Reports;
```

In the ReportForm Class Component's ComponentDidMout method call the updatState function like this:-

```
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        await this.props.onLoadReport();
        this.setState({ reports: this.props.reports });
        this.props.updateState(this.state);
    }
```

Comment: It does work, but could you please explain why? Also, after the changes, I get the warning: ```Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.```

Comment: " return (<option value={Object.keys(values)[0]}>{Object.values(values)[0]}</option>" in this code add key attribute to the option tag like this :- " return (<option value={Object.keys(values)[0]} key={ `key-${index}` }>{Object.values(values)[0]}</option>"
                                            );
                                        })}

Comment: Well in the updated code I copied the state of the ReportForm Component to the Reports Component and pass down the function which will update the state of the Report Component as a prop and called it in the componentDidMount after ReportForm setState function so that the state of Reports Component will always be the updated one.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Just wondering if it's the appropriate way to share state between components in React.